# Why my Highchart javascript always get the old data from DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I wrote a RoR app and I put a [Highchart's Javascript](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update) in the index page.
when I start my app and my [clockwork.rb](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) .
the clockwork will create new random data every minute in the DB.
And the Highchart JS will draw the last one every minute.

but here's problem.
the Highchart always draw the last one data in started time.
it can't get draw the NEW "last" data. 
What's happened?

here's part of my javascript
line 11 "<%= mydata.last.value%>" is how I get last data from DB

```
type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function() {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function() {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = <%= mydata.last.value%>;
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 60000);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In initial serie, do you have any points? It is realted with shifpting, try to addPoint wihtout shifting (i.e until achieve 10 points), and after achieve this edge, use addPoint with shifting.